# How can I change my pipeline to stream in Android and reduce the lag?

Tags: java, python, android, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm using gstream to stream with RTSP protocol from my camera connected to a jetson nano to an Android device.

At this moment I can see the camera in vlc with this:

```
e./test-launch "nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=(int)320,height=(int)240,format=(string)NV12,framerate=(fraction)15/1 ! omxh264enc name=omxh264enc control-rate=1 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline,stream-format=(string)byte-stream ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0"
```

But I have 2 seconds lag and I think the format is not valid for Android. I found some people who say that the current format I have is h264 MPEG-4 AVC Part 10.

I use VideoView to stream in Android.

edit: The lag was an vlc problem, I had a configuration with 1000ms.